# 24 Volt system with 2 outputs. Convert to 12 Volt Outputs

Tags: plc, hmi

[image]

What would I need to add to set up to get 2 outputs at 12 volts.  Outputs are 0 and 1.  I would assume relays.
Signal Outputs.  For a 3 Position 12V Solinoid.
Micro 820 2080-LC20-20QWB

Comment: what kind of outputs? signal? load? more details please (edit the question, no need to put in comments)

Comment: What 820 are you using? Depending on which one you should be able to use 12V directly on the relay outputs using the COM and OUT...

Comment: I figured it out. added 2 24 volt relays for outputs. Actuated the valve perfect. Thanks